# Python 3 - Hosting a server

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, server

Basically, I'm making a Game Server for my Python text-based game. What I want is to let each player make his own local server and/or public server but I don't seem to get it. I've tried this:

```
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = input("Enter an IP: ")
port = 10922
serversocket.bind((host, port))
```

But whenever I'm running it and type my own external IP, it throws me this error:
"OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context"

Edit: To add to this, it only works with host = "127.0.0.1" but the server isn't public that way.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: You should only bind to a *local* address. If you want to accept connections through any interface you can use the special IN_ADDR_ANY 0.0.0.0 address; `serversocket.bind(("0.0.0.0", port))`

Comment: To further explain, there's a certain point at the game which tells you "Do you want to host a LAN server or host a public server?". A server is needed so the player can play multiplayer-ish so I want to give the player the freedom to type whatever IP he wants to host it at.

Comment: You shouldn't query for an *IP*, but get them (local machine ones) via `socket.getaddrinfo("", 0)`. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50928002/why-cannot-bind-socket-to-localhost-for-outgoing-request/50933732#50933732 (it's for *UDP*, but the principle is the same), you might find smth useful.

Comment: Please read again the *local* word. You can connect to any address but can only bind to a *local* one.

Comment: So the server binds to a local address but it can accept any external address?

Comment: How do you imagine binding to _whatever IP_ if the server is not on that IP address? Bind to local (`0.0.0.0`), and make sure the server is reachable from the _outside_...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The reason it throws this error is because you are binding to an unknown address hence the error.**

To bind the socket to your IP, do: `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())` in the place of the address.

`socket.gethostname()` gets the hostname of the computer e.g. `DANS_PC`

`socket.gethostbyname()` looks up the IP of the hostname that is given in the parameters.

To make the server public however, do the same but port forward your computers IP address in your router settings.